# How do I fix the paths of my website?

Tags: joomla

I have Joomla 2.5.7 in my client's server updated recently from 1.6 to 1.7.

I did not make that site but I am responsible for it now. I prefer to make a site from zero.

Now users area clicking on the menu options and when joomla send them to a meta-url like `http://iap.pa.gov.br/acervo` they get the message `404 The requested URL /acervo was not found on this server.`

Would that be because they moved joomla folder from the root to root/iap (name of the site)?

If it is, what is the configuration to adapt to that new folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "http://iap.pa.gov.br" your main site? The target of the url seems right then. All links on that site seems to be fine. Please provide more informations of your problem.

Have you changed the SEO settings and forgot to clean the cache?

Comment: I moved the site from `/ipa` do `/` and reset the apache configuration to the root.